# Accepting Map<String, Object> in @Controller, but deserialize each Object into other specific classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, deserialization, jackson2

Let's say I have a class defined:

```
@Entity
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public class PurchaseOrder {
```

and

```
@Entity
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public class PurchaseOrderEntry {
```

Then, I have a controller that have to accept various kinds of data types, such as Integer, String, and other classes including `PurchaseOrder` and `PurchaseOrderEntry`.

```
@PostMapping("/complete")
public ResponseEntity<?> complete(
    @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> variables
)
```

However, the controller doesn't seem to recognize `PurchaseOrder` and `PurchaseOrderEntry` class. Every complex data types will be deserialized into LinkedHashMap<String, Object>. I thought `JsonTypeInfo` is supposed to help with serialization/deserialization, but it seems to only work on the serialization side.

How can I solve this deserialization issue?

**Edit:**
I think my approach to this problem is wrong. As pointed by the comments and answer, `JsonTypeInfo` may not be intended to solve my kind of problem. I'll post update if I ever found another solution.

Comment: `JsonTypeInfo` can use to deserialization. But not just the way you thought!

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonTypeInfo` is used when you have polymorphic types.
The best way to explain this is with an example.

Imagine you have the following class:

```java
public class Zoo {
    public Animal animal;

    @JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = As.PROPERTY, 
      property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")
    })
    public static class Animal {
        public String name;
    }

    @JsonTypeName("dog")
    public static class Dog extends Animal {
        public double barkVolume;
    }

    @JsonTypeName("cat")
    public static class Cat extends Animal {
        boolean likesCream;
        public int lives;
    }
}
```

If you have an object of `Zoo` with two animals in it (one `Cat` and one `Dog`) and you serialize them to JSON, then each of those animals would include an additional attribute (in this case `type`) with the corresponding `cat` or `dog` type.

If you later deserialize this JSON, Jackson will be able to instantiate a `Cat` and a `Dog` object based on this `type` attribute.

Full details can be checked [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-polymorphic-type-handling-annotations).

Comment: Thanks, I understand jackson better now, if only I can add `JsonSubType` to `Object`. I think I would need a different approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson doesn't know the relationship between `Object` and your `JsonTypeInfo`, you need to provide some hints.

Try this

```
@PostMapping
public Foo foo(@RequestBody Map<String, MyObject> variables) {}

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public interface MyObject {}

public class PurchaseOrderEntry implements MyObject {}
```

Edit:

I'm not sure if this works without `JsonSubTypes`. If it doesn't, you also need to add `JsonSubTypes` like the other answer suggested.

Comment: Using MyObject works without `JsonSubTypes`. However, I also need to be able to receive primitive data types like boolean (Boolean) and String. Maybe I need to see this problem from another angle.